# Trying to put an image at the bottom of Relative layout

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I am trying to create android app, where i need to place a wave image at the bottom      of a relative layout.but, the is a white space between the screen bottom and the wave image.please check out the xml code and the screenshot below, and let me know where i could have gone wrong.

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context=".MainActivity" >

   <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/imageship"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:src="@drawable/ship" />

  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/imagewaves"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:src="@drawable/waves"
      android:visibility="gone" />

  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/imagewaveshigh"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:src="@drawable/waveshigh"
      android:visibility="visible" />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try setting `android:scaleType = "fitEnd"`, if it wont work try some other "scaletypes".

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` in the wave ImageView.